# Why are outcomes from poisson regressions more precise than linear?

Tags: poisson-distribution, poisson-regression

I'll quickly qualify what I mean by "precise": I don't mean "correct" in any way. But, I was messing around running a lot (100s) of regression models, with an outcome that behaves a little bit Poisson-like but not obvious enough to definitely choose it over a linear model. So basically I ran ~500 different combinations of covariates, with the same outcome, using poisson, and then repeated exact same with linear. And the Poisson coefficients are all extremely similar, whereas the linear models' coefficients are much more spread out. What is the intuition behind why this would be the case?

Comment: What an interesting phenomenon, can you share the data, or a simulated dataset that behaves like it?

Comment: Poisson regression, in effect, inversely weights the observations by their estimated mean - a heteroskedasticity correction based upon the relationship between the variance and the mean of a Poisson distribution.   Linear regression does not.   So, if you have a few outlying observations with large means and correspondingly large variances, it can be that the Poisson regression is more stable - as it downweights those observations - than the linear regression.

Comment: It is unclear what you did. What do you mean by linear regression? Poisson regression can also be a linear regression/function (if you use an identity link function). But also, if you did a Poisson regression you may have used an exponential link function which changes the meaning of the coefficients by a lot. Other reasons for large coefficient changes might be heteroscedasticity, but this depends on the particular setup. There are a lot of ways explaining how this phenomenon may occur but it is difficult to comment/answer on it in detail if the details of your simulations/runs are not clear.

Comment: *"So basically I ran ~500 different combinations of covariates, with the same outcome"* What does this mean. Is this like keeping the outcome the same but changing the covariates as in some sort of Monte Carlo method where you permute the covariates?

Comment: In the most literal/practical sense, by linear regression I mean lm() in R or -reg- in Stata. And yes precisely, I kept the outcome and one "main" predictor variable the same, and changed the other coefficients.

Comment: @a_todd12 Could you add this and more explanation to your question. It is still unclear what you are doing. As an example why it is so ambiguous/unclear: in R I can get the same behaviour without Poisson regression. For instance when I use `as.numeric(replicate(10,lm(rpois(10,100)~1)$coefficients[1]))` and `as.numeric(replicate(10,glm(rpois(10,100)~1, family = gaussian(link = log))$coefficients[1]))`